# How to setup toll-free number in AWS SNS instead of the default?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-sns, aws-pinpoint

I am using AWS cognito to signup users and create new accounts for my users on my web-app. I authorize the user's phone number by sending a one-time-password via AWS SNS. Off-late there has been a message on my SNS dashboard which reads like this :
[image]

I am worried that cognito will stop sending one-time-passwords to users who signup on my website and because of that I might loose them. I have not done any custom setup as of now for my application. From reading through communities and aws documentation I figured I can use a toll-free number from Amazon Pinpoint instead. It fits my requirement but there is no documentation of how to plug this toll-free number into the cognito process. I have purchased a toll-free number but don't understand how to use it for sending phone verification otp. Would be great if someone could help me with this.Thanks.

Comment: I'm not 100% convinced that you need to worry about this.  Are you using just the default MFA provided by Cognito where they control the numbers or are you doing something custom where you are sending out SNS messages yourself?  If you are just doing MFA via Cognito, they own those numbers and AWS should be sending the SMSs with valid origination IDs.

Comment: I am not doing anything custom - just using the default cognito functionality where I have no control over the numbers they use to send messages. I am reading on other channels and forums that the toll-free number will be picked up automatically by cognito just like you mentioned. However my concern is because there is no aws documentation confirming this or the opposite. The only manual thing I did in SNS was to increase the spending limit because the default was $1 and the otps stopped coming and was back to normal when I submitted a request to increase it and the limit was increased.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the AWS documentation, you can use a Pre Sign-up Lambda Trigger. The pre sign-up Lambda function is triggered just before Amazon Cognito signs up a new user. It allows you to perform custom validation to accept or deny the registration request as part of the sign-up process. Because you can use a Lambda function, you can use custom logic within the Lambda function to meet your business requirements. This includes hooking into Pinpoint to achieve what you want to do. For more details:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-pre-sign-up.html

Comment: Okay, but as of now the process works without a pre sign-up lambda - do I need to implement custom logic in order to use a toll-free number instead of the default being used now? I am trying to find out what the process is to use a toll-free number instead of the default, feels like an over-kill to implement a whole new lamda trigger to achieve that.

Comment: According to the doc - this is the way to implement this functionality.

Comment: I use the amplify library to do user sign-ups and all user account activities - so I followed this document https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/emailpassword/q/platform/js#sign-up - to implement a lambda my entire signup logic will need to change with heavy application code modifications. Not sure if that's the right way to do it.